# Subtract values of specified subgroups from another within multiple larger groups

Tags: r, dplyr, repeat, subtraction

I have data shaped like this:

```
set.seed(123456)
domain <- as.factor(rep(c('alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo', 
                          'foxtrot', 'golf', 'hotel', 'india', 'juliet'), 
                        each = 8))
group <- as.factor(rep(c('group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3', 'group 4', 'group 5', 
                         'group 6', 'group 7', 'group 8'), 10))
freq <- signif(rnorm(80, mean = 1750, sd = 500), 1)
df <- data.frame(domain, group, freq)

df

    domain   group freq
1    alpha group 1 2000
2    alpha group 2 2000
3    alpha group 3 2000
4    alpha group 4 2000
5    alpha group 5 3000
6    alpha group 6 2000
7    alpha group 7 2000
8    alpha group 8 3000
9    bravo group 1 2000
10   bravo group 2 2000
11   bravo group 3 1000
12   bravo group 4 1000
13   bravo group 5 2000
14   bravo group 6 2000
15   bravo group 7 2000
16   bravo group 8 2000
17 charlie group 1 1000
18 charlie group 2 2000
19 charlie group 3 3000
20 charlie group 4 2000
21 charlie group 5 1000
22 charlie group 6 2000
...
```

I'm trying to subtract the freq value of group 1 from the value in group 5 for all 10 domains whilst retaining the original data frame. This code will be ran on multiple datasets and so needs to be automated and be easily reproducible across multiple users.

This is what I'm after, note changes to group 5 in each domain:

```
    domain   group freq
1    alpha group 1 2000
2    alpha group 2 2000
3    alpha group 3 2000
4    alpha group 4 2000
5    alpha group 5 **1000**
6    alpha group 6 2000
7    alpha group 7 2000
8    alpha group 8 3000
9    bravo group 1 2000
10   bravo group 2 2000
11   bravo group 3 1000
12   bravo group 4 1000
13   bravo group 5 **0**
14   bravo group 6 2000
15   bravo group 7 2000
16   bravo group 8 2000
17 charlie group 1 1000
18 charlie group 2 2000
19 charlie group 3 3000
20 charlie group 4 2000
21 charlie group 5 **0**
22 charlie group 6 2000
...
```

I've tried using `group_by()` from dplyr in combination with `ifelse()` statements or base R to do this to no avail. Similar questions on this site aim to subtract a value from all others in a group which is not what I'm after.

If anyone could assist with a (what I imagine is a fairly simple) dplyr command to get this I'd appreciate it.

This is my first question, so please let me know if there are any housekeeping rules I could follow in a better manner!

Comment: Great first question, Rlearn! Only "housekeeping" rule I would suggest is to include `set.seed()` when using random numbers to provide sample data, as it ensures reproducibility. Also, dont tag `rstudio` unless you have a question about the actual R Studio user interface

Comment: Thank you jpsmith, I'll keep this in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply use `mutate` here with an `ifelse` and  little bit of subsetting and `.by = domain` in the following way:

```
df %>%
  mutate(diffvals = ifelse(!(group %in% "group 5"), freq,
                              freq[group == "group 5"] - freq[group == "group 1"]), 
            .by = domain)
```

Output - note I created a new variable (`diffvals`) just for demonstration/verification purposes. You could overwrite the original variable per your desired output by changing `mutate(diffvals = ...` to `mutate(freq = ...)`

```
    domain   group freq diffvals
1    alpha group 1 2000     2000
2    alpha group 2 2000     2000
3    alpha group 3 2000     2000
4    alpha group 4 2000     2000
5    alpha group 5 3000     1000
6    alpha group 6 2000     2000
7    alpha group 7 2000     2000
8    alpha group 8 3000     3000
9    bravo group 1 2000     2000
10   bravo group 2 2000     2000
11   bravo group 3 1000     1000
12   bravo group 4 1000     1000
13   bravo group 5 2000        0
14   bravo group 6 2000     2000
15   bravo group 7 2000     2000
16   bravo group 8 2000     2000
17 charlie group 1 1000     1000
18 charlie group 2 2000     2000
19 charlie group 3 3000     3000
20 charlie group 4 2000     2000
21 charlie group 5 1000        0
22 charlie group 6 2000     2000
...
```

Comment: Cheers, this does get the numbers I need, but I'd like for these to be subtracted from the values in the original data.frame whilst retaining the original frame. I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: @Rlearn - no problem - could you edit your quesiton to include your desired output?

Comment: @Rlearn - see edit, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I added the output I'm after, it's a bit different to what you've produced but not far off. I'll be sure to include this in my future questions

Comment: @Rlearn gotcha - see edit and let me know if that does the trick. good luck!

Comment: I had to swap the `.by = domain` argument to a prior `group_by(domain) %>%` function, but this worked! Thanks a lot! 

To clarify, I used this exact command before but used `freq[group == 5]` instead of your `!(group %in% "group 5")` in the `test =` argument. What does the %in% command do here?

Comment: @Rlearn great! The `.by` command is only with newer versions of R. In this context, `%in%` is the exact same as using `==` - that was just a habit of mine, though  if we were looking at other groups,`%in%` would be preferred (i.e. `group %in% c(1, 4, 6)` instead of `group == 1 & group == 4 & group == 6`)

Comment: I'm still running build 4.1.3 so that makes sense. So it was my call for the freq of group 5, rather than just calling for group 5 that was the problem. Seems like %in% is far more concise. Thanks for all this!

Answer (score 1):

Might be benefitical to work with a wide format here

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = freq, names_glue = "group_{group}") %>% 
  mutate(across(group_5, ~ .x - group_1))

# A tibble: 10 × 9
   domain group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 group_6 group_7 group_8
    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1      1    1000     500    3000    3000    1000    2000     600     400
 2      2    2000    2000    2000    2000       0    2000    2000    2000
 3      3    2000    2000    2000    2000    1000    1000    1000    2000
 4      4    1000    2000    2000    2000    1000    1000    2000    1000
 5      5    2000    2000    2000    1000       0    2000    1000    1000
 6      6    2000    2000    2000    2000       0    2000    1000    1000
 7      7    2000    1000    1000    3000       0    1000    1000    2000
 8      8    3000    1000    2000    2000   -2000    3000    2000    2000
 9      9    2000    2000    2000    1000    1000    2000    2000    2000
10     10    2000    2000    1000    2000   -1000    1000    2000    2000
```

Comment: My actual dataset is made up of categorical factors for group and domain rather than numeric values, so this approach would require a bit of renaming, but seems like it would work. Thank you! I should have made my question data a bit alike to what I have so I'll keep that in mind for my next one

Comment: @Rlearn you are welcome to edit your question and ill try to answer accordingly:)

Comment: The data is still the same, no?

Comment: Apologies, this was meant for the above answer, now I really have changed it!